# Stateless component with nested component property

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to use component like this:

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.Column>
  {/*some content*/}
 </Grid.Column>
</Grid>
```

Grid.tsx

```
export interface GridProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
}

const Grid: React.SFC<GridProps> =({ children, ...props }) =>
        <div {...props}>
            {children}
        </div>

export interface GridColumnProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
    size: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4,
    centered?: false
}

const Column: React.SFC<GridColumnProps> = ({ children, ...props }) =>
    <div {...props}>
        {children}
    </div>

Grid.Column = Column;
```

At the last line I have an error "Column doesn't exists on type StatelessComponent|GridProps|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a custom type for `Grid` one that is both `React.SFC<GridColumnProps>` and has a property named  `Column`

```
type GridType = React.SFC<GridProps> & { Column: React.SFC<GridColumnProps> } 
const Grid: GridType =(({ children, ...props }) =>
        <div {...props}>
            {children}
        </div>) as GridType // Use a type assertion as our function does not have the Column Property yet

Grid.Column = Column;
```